# how to ( pascal : procedure of object ) in c++

Tags: c++

I want to pass a class function as a parameter of C function 
in Pascal. It is achieved with the keyword (procedure of object) so the compiler will take care of 'this' parameter.
But it seems complicated in c++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*func)(void);

class Class{
public:
    void sub(void)
    {
      printf("Foo");
    }
};

void test(func f)
{
  f();
}

int main()
{
 Class c;
 test(c.sub);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that in C++ non-static member functions have a hidden first argument, that becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function. That means a pointer to a member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a (non-member) function. If you search a little you should have found hundred of thousands of pages explaining this, including a number of duplicate questions here on SO.

Comment: thanks Joachim , i did already , but i didn't find a simple case like the code above

Comment: i mean , am just looking for a simple solution , far away from templates and c++11

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the function to take a generic function type, either making it a template:

```
template <typename F>
void test(F f) {
    f();
}
```

or using type erasure:

```
#include <functional>

void test(std::function<void()> f) {
    f();
}
```

Then use either `std::bind` or a lambda to bind the member function to the object:

```
test(std::bind(&Class::sub, &c));
test([&]{c.sub();});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for similar issue. There is an answer from someone zayats80888 (thank you).

```
    #include <functional>
        using TEventHandler = std::function<void(int)>;
        
        class Button
        {
          TEventHandler onClick;
          public:
            Button(){ onClick = NULL;};
            void Run() {
             if (onClick) onClick(42);
            };
        };
         
        class Page
        {
          Button Bnt1;
          void ClickHandler(int Arg){/*do smth by Btn1->onClick*/};
          Page() {
            Btn1 = new Button();
            Btn1->onClick = [this](int arg) { goToCountersPage(arg); };
          }
        }
    
    Page Page1;
    void main() {
     Page1 = new Page();
     //
    }
```